# .Net C# Website with live synchronization, Google spreadsheets like

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity

I am looking to develop a website with limited functionality but the following outlines :
- Main screen is a grid
- Different users can edit the grid, which directly updates the database 
- The database updates are impacted on the different users so that when 1 user updates the grid, another user sees the update directly, without reloading the grid

I would like to implement this using ASP.Net / C# / Entity framework, could someone please let me know if that is feasible ?

Answer (score 2):

yes it is..... you just want to use ajax calls for live updating.

or use something like SignalR   -  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: +1. answer is the much better than one should expect to "product X does Y, is it possible to implement Y?" kind on question.